# Случайное отображение одного из четырех блоков

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. У меня четыре блока с разними id (id="pic_1", id="pic_2", id="pic_3", id="pic_4"). Все они скрыты при помощи display:none. Можете подсказать скрипт как сделать,чтобы при перезагрузке страницы один из этих блоков случайным выбором получал display:block? И вообще делается ли так, или я все усложняю? Собираюсь изучать JS, но пока его совершенно не знаю...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Как пример, можно так:

```js
function getRandomValue (array) {
  return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
}

var pics = document.querySelectorAll('.list > div');

getRandomValue(pics).style.display = '';
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div id="pic-1" style="display: none;">1</div>
  <div id="pic-2" style="display: none;">2</div>
  <div id="pic-3" style="display: none;">3</div>
  <div id="pic-4" style="display: none;">4</div>
</div>
```

**Вся суть:** вы берете набор нужных вам блоков (их можно получить любой выборкой, нужно смотреть что такое `селекторы`). И мы имеем массив элементов на странице, и с помощью метода `random` получаем рандомное значение из количества всех найденных элементов выборки (Я вывел это в отдельный метод). И затем обращаемся к полученному элементу и убираем у него стиль `display`

Answer (score 3):

```js
document.getElementById("pic-" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 + 1)).style.display = '';
```

```html
<div id="pic-1" style="display: none;">1</div>
<div id="pic-2" style="display: none;">2</div>
<div id="pic-3" style="display: none;">3</div>
<div id="pic-4" style="display: none;">4</div>
```

Comment: если попробовать запустить сниппет с вашим кодом несколько раз, то можно поймать ошибку :)

Comment: уже исправил ----------